# Nginx - Setting root location with spaces in path

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to configure `nginx` for my project. Step by steps:

- Create config file `myproject`

  ```
  --/etc/nginx/sites-available
  ----myproject
  ```
- Content of `myproject` file

  ```
  server {
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;

      root "/path/to/html/My Project/company/myproject";
      index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
      server_name myproject.localhost;

      location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;

              location = /index.php {
                      include                 /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                      fastcgi_pass            unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                      fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME "/media/path/to/html/My Project/company/myproject/index.php";
              }
      }
  }
  ```

Restart service nginx and try to load `myproject.locahost` in browser, I got "File not found."

View latest line in nginx error log, I got below error

```
9055#9055: *4 stat() "/media/path/to/html/My Project/company/myproject/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: myproject.localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "myproject.localhost"
9055#9055: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: myproject.localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "myproject.localhost"
```

If I move it to a directory path without space, It seems to work.
How can I define this path to make it work?

Comment: can you escape space and check like `My Project` with `My\ Project`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use path with spaces in file or directory names. But in general Unix file or directory names can contain any character other than / (which is always a directory separator) and null bytes (which you can't use =D). Try to not use spaces, $, ;, |, <, >, etc. in file or directory names, or you should escape them using backslash symbol \ behind escaping symbol.